# Division of two aggregration metric of kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to do the division of two aggregation metric of kibana. I am getting the count of two values and i want to divide both of them.

Is there is any way to do it.

Kibana is generating this elastic search request :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "1": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "1-bucket>_count"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "ms.keyword"
      }
    },
    "1-bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ms.keyword",
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "indiviualCount": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "(doc['campaign'].empty) ? 0 : ((1.0/doc['campaign'].value) * 100)",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "docvalue_fields": [
    "edrTimestamp",
    "timestamp"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way we can achieve it in Kibana. I was think to use scripted field but where it will be written. Someone recommended me to use Pipeline aggregation but i am not able to achieve it

Answer (score 2):

I am searching for an answer for a while and my workaround is to use the vertical bar chart.

1. You need add 2 metric, each metric set to "sum" for your fields (you can manage your fields under "Management side tab" -> "scripted fields" to add or subtract your fields for the correctness of the division).
2. Switch to Metrics & Axes tab, set both metric to "stacked" mode. Set your y-axes to percentage mode.
   [image: Percentage image]